# How to get html-string from html-string cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works in Chrome and FF, but not Safari :/

```
var content = '<div><span><p>Can you catch me?</p></span></div>';
content = $.parseXML(content);
var span = $(content).find('span').html();
```

I need the output as a string. And I would prefer nothing to be put into the DOM.

In Chrome and FireFox it outputs 
"`<p>`Can you catch me?`</p>`" 
Which is what I want.

If you dump this JS into the Safari console, you get a document output, but its the whole thing, not just the span.

Comment: What are you trying to have span equal to exactly?

Comment: In Chrome and FireFox it outputs "<p>Can you catch me?</p>"

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
var $content = $('<div><span><p>Can you catch me?</p></span></div>');
var $span = $content.find('span');
```

now span will be the jquery wrapped html `<span><p>can you catch me?</p></span>`.

If you want the `<p>` element you would do:

```
var $p = $content.find('p');
```

Answer (score 0):

More reliable - use document:

```
<div id="temp" style="display: none;"></div>
```

and

```
$("#temp").html("<div><span>...");
var span = $("span", "#temp").html();
$("#temp").html("");
```